# Google Page Speed API Path?

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I' wondering if anyone can shed some light on the PageSpeed API results.

I am trying to access specific elements from the document. I have used the "selector" but that can return multiple elements. I am curious if there is a way to use the the path result and convert this to XPATH?

Comment: Path: "5,HTML,2,BODY,3,DIV,2,MAIN,0,DIV,0,DIV,0,DIV,0,DIV,1,DIV,0,DIV,1,DIV,0,DIV,3,P,0,A",

As mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

I was recently working on pulling specific elements from PageSpeed results too, but I parsed the JSON data and extracted my desired data from there. This seemed more straightforward once I understood how to parse the JSON. I set up a loop because I had hundreds of URLs, but for simpler purposes this may be helpful. This is what I used:

```
url = ['https://www.yourwebsite.com/']

   API_Key = "yoUrKeY"
   baseURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url="
   strategy = "mobile"
   response_url = baseURL+url+'&key='+API_Key+'&strategy='+strategy
   response = requests.get(response_url).json()
   url_id = response['originLoadingExperience']['id']
   overall_score = response['lighthouseResult']['categories']['performance']['score']*100
   fcp_score = response['originLoadingExperience']['metrics']['FIRST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_MS']['percentile']/1000
    
   print(url_id, overall_score, fcp_score)
```